# can traefik listen on connections from a subnet

Tags: nginx

Can traefik be configured to accept connections only from a particular subnet / ip address?

For example, in nginx I can define:

```
location / {
  # block one workstation
  deny    192.168.1.1;
  # allow anyone in 192.168.1.0/24
  allow   192.168.1.0/24;
  # drop rest of the world
  deny    all;
}
```

I searched all traefik documentation but couldn't find anything about this.

Can this be done in traefik?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to update, I posted this question on the traefik slack (https://traefik.slack.com/messages/support/) and this is the reply I got from Emile (traefik maintainer): "this is not possible in traefik for now sorry".